# How do you install ubuntu 13.04 on a custom built computer using a cd?

Tags: 13.04

I need help. i recently built a computer using parts in my house. this computer does not currently have an os. so i would like to set up the BIOS so that it would install it automatically. Here is it's specs
OS:None
HDD:160 GB
RAM: 2 GB
CPU:Intel Pentium 4@2.66 GHZ

Comment: You will need to create a USB stick or DVD using another computer.  Once you have done that however just follow the instructions here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/107450)

Answer (score 0):

That hardware should work fine, but you'll need to set your BIOS to boot from a (1) USB drive, (2)  a DVD drive, or, worst case, (3) a CD which will do just enough of an install to get online and finish the job. The only reason you'd choose (3) is if your hardware won't boot from a USB and only includes a CD drive, not a DVD.

You'll need to download the .iso file, then create a bootable image on the USB or DVD. Simply copying the .iso file to a DVD or USB will not do. Assuming you're using Windows for this step on another system, you'll need software to do this. `unetbootin` has a Windows version and is free. Google is your friend.

When you've got the bootable DVD or USB, boot to it. Try to have a WIFI card installed, or ethernet plugged in. Play around with it, get online. When you're ready, double click on the `Install` icon on the desktop, and follow directions. You'll want to take over the whole hard drive. Don't be shy about starting over and re-installing a couple of times, there are several options you have to choose from, like whole-disk encryption, that you'll wish you'd chosen otherwise.